# How to center div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with centering div in HTML (vertical & horizontal). My code looks something like this:

```
<div id="container">SOME HTML</div>

#container{
    width: 366px;
    height: 274px;
    margin: 50%;
    top: -137px;
    left: -188px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Only chrome center this div in to the middle of the screen.

Comment: I may be missing something, but how are you expecting to centre a div if you're using absolute positioning?  Are you assuming that all screens have the same size and resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick (vertical & horizontal):

```
#container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 366px;
    height: 274px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -183px; /* half width */
    margin-top: -137px; /* half height */
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This will center the `<div>` horizontally:

```
#container{
    width: 366px;
    height: 274px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Centering vertically is not quite simple, you maybe have to use javascript for that, or you try [this css solution](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
#container{
    width: 366px;
    height: 274px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -137px 0 0 -188px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
#container {
    // Your other values, but remove position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
#wrapper, #container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 500px;
    width: 600px;
}

#wrapper {
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}

#container {
    background: yellow;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
}
```

And you're HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Centered Div</h1>
        <p>
            This div has been centered within your browser window.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

That will center the `<div>` in the middle of the browser window.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.cont{
  background-color: tomato;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color: teal;
  color:#fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Should be fine to use just CSS:

here is the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/65urC/)

```
#container{
    width: 366px;
    height: 274px;
    margin: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}​
```